# Git repository tags merging

Tags: git, github, tags

i need little help regarding git repository. I have created many tags in repository like `v1.2.1` to `v1.2.9` than i have made some changes in tag `v1.2.4` and push changes and delete old tag and recreate new one with same name using below commands.

```
git branch v1.2.4-bugfix v1.2.4
git checkout v1.2.4-bugfix
//commit changes
git tag -f v1.2.4
git push origin :v1.2.4
git push origin v1.2.4
```

Now issue is that how i can merge these changes into other tags like i want these changes in all tags that created after `v1.2.4`

Please help me to figure out the solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tag is just an alias to a commit.
You can check them out, merge and do any other git command which you can do on any of your branches.

Its not clear what you want to do.

You have tagged commit with a new tags and now you want to merge this code to all other tags.

On which branches are those tags? to which branch you want to merge it into?

The tag can be on all your branches and you have to merge it to some branch, what will be with the other branches?

Comment: all tags are in master branch. I have created tags after merge commits into master like `git tag -a 'v1.2.3' commit_id -m 'message'`

Comment: So if its ll in the master branch so all your code is in this branch. i miss the problem. You have all your code in master

Comment: when i do click on a tag in my repository than it show different source code from master branch. I have annotated tags and i think these type tags treated as a separate branch. Issue is that i have made some changes in a tag source that created long time ago and i want that those changes also reflect in other tags those created after that changed tags.

Comment: Annotated tags are not branches, they are bobs just like any commit but with name (human readable) If you want to apply the changed to other tags, move the tags to the latest commit, A commit can have multiple tags